# Why does my file copy silently fail on explorer on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a large number of files in a complicated directory tree on a flash drive that I am attempting to copy onto a Windows 7 system. The largest individual file is 2 MB. If I drag the files to copy them using explorer, or right click to copy and paste even, nothing happens - no dialog, no files copying, no error message. If I select the subdirectories one by one and copy them over, most of them work, but some (3/12) exhibit the same behaviour as the parent directory.

As I go further down the directory tree I find the same behaviour: Most subdirs copy over, but some do not and I need to go into those and copy manually. They themselves are either composed entirely of subdirectories with none of their own (which copy fine), or some with subdirectories, possibly similarly bugged.

- I can copy all the files over manually by going through subdirectories myself. I encounter no warnings on these files. My Windows Vista laptop does not encounter the same difficulty with these files.
- I am not reaching any filename length limits.
- I have plenty of hard drive space.
- None of the files appear to be corrupt.
- The flash drive is FAT32, the hard drive NTFS.
- The maximum directory depth on the flash drive is 6, and it's copied 3 folders deep into the HDD's filesystem, for 9 max depth on the HDD.

Comment: Any resolution on this in the end? I'm getting the same issue today under Windows 10. I note the target drive for the copy is a networked drive. Copy works fine to local drives.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's up, but I have just suggested RichCopy in another thread and it's much more robust than the built-in copy functions so perhaps give it a try - it's from Microsoft and free to download:

http://www.pkguild.com/2009/08/introducing-richcopy-your-robocopy-replacement/